# Does boost not include a /lib directory?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cmake

I am trying to build the boost `1.74.0` libraries from source in order to generate make files with `cmake`. I fail to understand: According to the boost install page, the building of the library should generate the `lib` path. However I only see the lib**s** folder.
I built boost using

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=system
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
./b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++0x
```

and got the output

```
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached)
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached)

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.



Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - contract                 : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - fiber                    : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - headers                  : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - nowide                   : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - stacktrace               : not building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - type_erasure             : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...found 165 targets...
...updating 10 targets...
boost-install.generate-cmake-config- bin.v2/libs/headers/build/stage/boost_headers-config.cmake
boost-install.generate-cmake-config- bin.v2/libs/system/build/stage/boost_system-config.cmake
boost-install.generate-cmake-config-version- bin.v2/libs/system/build/stage/boost_system-config-version.cmake
common.copy /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/boost_system-config.cmake
common.copy /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/boost_system-config-version.cmake
common.copy /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0/boost_headers-config.cmake
boost-install.generate-cmake-config-version- bin.v2/libs/headers/build/stage/boost_headers-config-version.cmake
common.copy /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0/boost_headers-config-version.cmake
...updated 10 targets...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib
```

So I assumed it worked. I see the `include` path. But I cannot see the `lib` path. There is only the `libs` path?

Where ist the lib path? Why didnt it get built.

Edit:
The relevant extract from the documentation is the following. As you can see, it states that at top level there should be a lib\ path? Is the documentation wrong?

```
boost_1_73_0\ .................The “boost root directory”
   index.htm .........A copy of www.boost.org starts here
   boost\ .........................All Boost Header files
   lib\ .....................precompiled library binaries
   libs\ ............Tests, .cpps, docs, etc., by library
     index.html ........Library documentation starts here
     algorithm\
     any\
     array\
                     …more libraries…
   status\ .........................Boost-wide test suite
   tools\ ...........Utilities, e.g. Boost.Build, quickbook, bcp
   more\ ..........................Policy documents, etc.
   doc\ ...............A subset of all Boost library docs
```

(This is taken from the documentation 1.74, despite that it says 1.73 at the top of this extract).
The reason I ask all this, is because I want to explicitly hand the different folders to `cmake`.

Comment: So, there IS path `/home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/libs` but there IS NOT path `/home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib`. Am I correctly understand your problem?

Comment: @Tszvarev: Almost. There no `/home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/lib`, but `/home/vm-umic/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib`. Why? is the documentation wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#the-boost-distribution) shows what would you get after unpacking (`tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_73_0.tar.bz2`) the **archive**. If you build Boost, the directory structure could differ. Whether `stage/` subdirectory is created or not depends on options you pass when build the Boost.

Comment: What happens after installation? You are now only building Boost but not installing it according to your commands. The installation prefix may be need to be specified to the build commands.

Comment: use `./b2 install` to install boost to a directory you provided after building it, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install And btw: after doing this you don't need to provide the directories to cmake manually since the installation comes with cmake configuration scripts allowing you to use `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ... CONFIG)` which should provide you with imported targets (`Boost::<component_name>`)containing the info as long as the dir you installed boost to is in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The `libs` directory you found is where the sources (library TUs, test, examples and documentation) live.

Look closely:

[image]

> Just to be sure, note the `stage/` in there.

Comment: Added some comment to dispel the most likely confusion.

Comment: okay, but the documentation states otherwise or am I overlooking something? See my Edit of the original question, because the documentation states that the lib path shouldnt be under `/stage/lib` but rather directly under `/lib`. As stated in the edit, I need these pathes for including `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` because the automatic finding does not work unfortunately.